# How to use real 'y' values on y-axis using imshow

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to use the actual y values used to plot an image as the y-axis in imshow.
My code looks like this at the moment:

```
x = np.arange(0,5,0.1)
y = np.arange(0,5,0.1)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
a1 = X**2+Y**2
a2 = X**2+Y**2
a3 = X**2+Y**2

a = np.concatenate((a1,a2,a3), axis=1)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(a, cmap=cm.RdYlGn, aspect = 'auto')

plt.axvline(a1.shape[1]); plt.axvline(a1.shape[1]+a2.shape[1])
plt.show()
```

However the y-axis values being shown on the graph are completely wrong.
Is there a way to make the y-axis show the actual values used to calculate the values a1,a2,a3.
That is, I would like the y-axis to start at 0 (from the bottom) and end at 5.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following lines to your code after `ax.imshow()` and see if this is what you want to have. First, I set the ticks at the "real" y-axis value-locations and then modify the tick-labels to display the values you want. `[::-1]` simply reverses the array

```
ax.set_yticks(range(0, 51, 10))
ax.set_yticklabels(range(6)[::-1])
```

[image]